# Dojo 1.1: Event when leaving / switching tab?

Tags: javascript, dojo

We habe to use an old Dojo Version 1.1.x, our problem is to find an event fired when an Tab is changed (user leaving the tab).

Scenario: There is a Form inside an Tab, data is edited and the tab is left without saving, now we are looking for an way to prevent this.

```
    dojo.connect(this.myTabPoint, "onShow", function(evt){
        alert('X');
    });
```

Works fine, but so we have to implement the check on every other tab (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dojo 1.1.2 there is a method `_hideChild(/*Widget*/ page)` in `dijit.layout.StackContainer` (i.e. the superclass of `dijit.layout.TabContainer`), which will invoke `onHide` method of page/tab (e.g. `ContentPane`) if it exists.

The problem is there is no `onHide` method in `dijit.layout.ContentPane`, so you should add `onHide` stub method to ContentPane somewhere early in your code:

```
dojo.extend(dijit.layout.ContentPane, {
    onHide: function() {
        // stub method
    }
});
```

Then all you need to do is `dojo.connect` to `onHide` method on a particular tab/ContentPane:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("tab1"), "onHide", function() {
    console.log("tab1 is hidden now");
});
```